# How to pass two values in URL body in JSON swift?

Tags: json, swift, api, url

I am trying to add parameters in URL body like below

```
func getUserProfile() {
    let deviceId: String = "HardcodeDEVICEIDforiTaag"//(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!
    let personalId: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USERID") ?? ""
    let headers = ["deviceid": deviceId,"userType": "personal","key": personalId]

    let string = "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/getprofile/"
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: string)
    let requestedUserType = URLQueryItem(name: "requestedUserType", value: "personal")

    let requestedItem = URLQueryItem(name: "requestedKey", value: personalId)
    urlComponents?.queryItems = [requestedItem, requestedUserType]
    let urlStr = urlComponents?.url
    print(urlStr?.absoluteString)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:urlStr)! as URL,cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers as! [String : String]
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String :AnyObject]
                    self.userModel = ProfileModel.init(fromDictionary: jsonObject)
                    print("profile json \(jsonObject)")
                    print("profile personalid 2222\(personalId)")

                    if (self.userModel?.userId) != nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.updateUserDetails()
                            self.addressTableview.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else { DispatchQueue.main.async { Constants.showAlertView(alertViewTitle: "", Message: "No user data found", on: self)}}
                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            } else {
                //Constants.showAlertView(alertViewTitle: "", Message: "Something went wrong, Please try again", on: self)

            }
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

then got error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'String'

i got above error when i am trying to add url to request.

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: print `personalId` ..........

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes personalId coming in print

Comment: Your last url row is badly formatted, it is missing an '=' and has spaces in it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes ur correct but + it need spaces.. thats why.. but i will add "="

Comment: @JoakimDanielson.. thank you only "=" was missing added working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how one should create a url with different components:

```swift
let string = "http://itaag-env-1-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/getprofile"
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: string)
let requestedItem = URLQueryItem(name: "requestedKey", value: "yourReqKey")
let requestedUserType = URLQueryItem(name: "requestedUserType", value: "personal")
urlComponents?.queryItems = [requestedItem, requestedUserType]
let url = urlComponents?.url
print(url?.absoluteString)
```

Edit: Finally use this code to get your request :-

```swift
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```

Comment: thank you, but when i add your code and adding url to request then it says `Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'String'` .. how to solve this

Comment: @swift Why are you converting URL to String then again to URL?